# Need to update the tabs on picklist selection in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lightning-tabset

Based on the picklist selection i need to update the tab values in lwc. On the initial load of the page tabs are displaying correctly. But when changing the picklist values tabs are not rerendering with the new values. In the console i am able to see that new data is available in console based on my picklist selection.Below is my code.

HTML Template

---

```
<!-- picklist -->
<template if:true={multiTerritoryUser}>
    <lightning-combobox name="territory" label="Territory" value='' placeholder={dispLabel}
                        options={terOptions} onchange={handleChange} style="color: #000;">
    </lightning-combobox>
</template>
<!-- tabset-->
<template if:true={prgGrpLst}>
    <lightning-tabset >
        <template for:each={prgGrpLst} for:item="acc">
            <lightning-tab key={acc} label={acc}></lightning-tab>
        </template>
    </lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

JavaScript

---

```
@track terOptions = [];
@track prdLst = [];
//Fetching territory values for the current logged in user and handling if the territory is changed
@wire(getTerritoryDetails)
terInfoLst({error,data}){
    if(data){
        let picklistOptions = [];
        data.forEach(key => {
            picklistOptions.push({
                label: key.Territory2.DeveloperName,
                value: key.Territory2Id
            })
        });
        this.terOptions = picklistOptions;
    }
    else if(error){
        window.console.log('error ====> '+JSON.stringify(error))
    }
}
handleChange(event) {
    //const selectedoption  = event.detail.selectedValue;
    const selectedoption = event.detail.value;
    console.log('selectedoption =======>' + selectedoption);
    //logic for updating the product groups upon the selection of product groups
    getProductTabDetails({terId: selectedoption})
        .then(prdresult => {
            this.dataprodArray = prdresult;
            let tempprdArray = [];
            this.dataprodArray.forEach(function (prdelement) {
                tempprdArray.push(prdelement);
            });
            this.prgGrpLst = tempprdArray;
            console.log('tempprdArray =============>' + JSON.stringify(tempprdArray));
            console.log('prdLst ===============>' + JSON.stringify(prdLst));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('prod error' + error)
        });
}
```

Apex class

---

My method returns list of string of names:

```
List<Product> prd =[select name from product where id=:selId];
```

Comment: really hard to read w/o formatting.  can you edit your question with formatting enabled?  Also a good idea to post your html

Comment: @willard It was present, just not indented correctly, so was "rendered" by the browser, which makes nothing appear.

Comment: Have you defined the attribute `prgGrpLst`? If not then define that, otherwise your code looks good to me.

Comment: yes.  i am getting "productgroup error undefined"